# Connect to WiFi using C#

Tags: c#, android, wifi

I am going to develop an application which connect android devices via **WiFi**. But my **PC has not wifi** facility. Is their any procedure to simulate the wifi connection **without using the WiFi adapter on PC**? (but I have a LAN Connection)

Comment: I seriously suggest you get a wifi connection.

Comment: This is kind of like asking if you can practice programming without a a computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you'll be using Sockets in your c# code... they don't know/care whether you are connected to the network using cable or wifi... it's just another ethernet interface

Perhaps what you mean is that you want to simulate a "slower/unstable" connection?

In any case, at some point you will define a communication protocol that you will use on top of TCP/IP (or UDP/IP) in order to communicate between the PC and the Android device, and that is what you will want to simulate and test.

- You could create a PC version of the Android app, connect to it via the localhost (127.0.0.1)
- You could start the Android debugger, set up networking and connect to it
- You could run Android in a Virtual Machine (vmware, virtualbox, etc) [Use Android for x86](http://www.android-x86.org/)
- If your Android device has an ethernet interface, connect it to your network and put it into flight mode every now and then to simulate an interruption in communication (wifi disconnect)

All these solutions will allow you to simulate communication without a wifi device